# Gunicorn: Failed At step EXEC spawning No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to get my gunicorn setup. Following is my config file for the systemmd config file:

```
# Unit section is used to specify metadata and dependencies
[Unit]
Description=DEMO

# only start once the network target has been reached
After=network.target



# Service section specify the user and group that we want the process to run under
[Service]
# www-data group assigned to facilitate easy communication with nginx
Group=www-data

# path to working directory
WorkingDirectory=/srv/demo/git

# path to virtual environment
Environment="PATH=/srv/demo/git/venv/bin"

ExecStart=/srv/demo/git/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=5 --bind unix:git.sock --log-level=debug wsgi:app --timeout 3600
#--workers=5 --threads=2 --worker-class=gthread 



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~                                                                                                       
~                                                                                                       
~
```

And my virtual environment folder does contain gunicorn:

[image]

But I am still unable to run this, the systemmd file says that it was unable to find gunicorn. No such file or directory:

[image]

i have uninstall gunicorn from outside my virtual env. But when i do a which gunicorn it shows me the path to be /usr/bin/gunicorn. When i put this path, it dosnt throw the same error but simply says that the apt_pkg and gunicorn module wasnt found but not a directory error. Is this a path issue? If so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 9):

**I hope following steps will be helpful to solve this problem....**

> Step 1: cd ~/myprojectdir

> Step 2: source myprojectenv/bin/activate

> Step 3: which gunicorn

> Step 4: Paste that into the path section of the ‘ExecStart’ value exchange ‘/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service’ by which guicorn '..../path"

> Step 5: sudo systemctl daemon-reload

> Step 6: sudo systemctl restart gunicorn

> Step 7: sudo systemctl status gunicorn

Comment: I had a similar problem when I typed which gunicorn.  It didn't show anything.
Ended up removing the whole venv and reinstalled it plus the whole requirements.txt.  That fixed the problem.

Comment: worked for me november 20, 2022